# How to manually create an Instagram token with the public_content scope

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How to manually generate an Instagram API auth token that has additional scopes, besides just `basic`?

Answer (score 0):

https://instagramtoken.com is a tool that generates an Instagram auth token in a couple clicks. It is free and secure. Also, unlike many of the other tools for manually generating Instagram tokens, you can specify scopes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries to get public info.

PHP: https://github.com/raiym/instagram-php-scraper

JAVA: https://github.com/raiym/instagram-java-scraper

NodeJS: https://github.com/slang800/instagram-screen-scrape